# How to reproduce this keyword overview?

Tags: syntax, grammar

I need to describe keywords in a TeX document. It should look similar like the keyword section of the C# specification:

[image]

I need some advice on how I can achieve this. Is this a transparent table? Can I use the syntax package here?

Comment: The font style is `\sffamily` (or, if fixed spacing is required, `\ttfamily`).  A left-aligned `tabular` environment should be able to achieve it simply.

Comment: Works great! Can you turn your comment into an answer - I will accept it then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, I used `\sffamily` for the keyword style, and `tabular` to array the keywords. If a fixed-width font is required, then `\ttfamily` can be used in lieu of `\sffamily`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textit{keyword::} one of

{\centering\sffamily\tabcolsep=2.5ex\relax
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
abstract & as & base& bool& break\\
byte & case & catch & char & checked\\
class & const & continue & decimal & default\\
delegate & do & double & delse & enum\\
...&&&&\\
unsafe & ushort & using & virtual & void\\
volatile & while&&&
\end{tabular}\par}\smallskip

\noindent The following identifiers have special meaning in the syntactic grammar but they
are not keywords: \textsf{add} (\S17.7), \textsf{alias} (\S16.3),...
\end{document}
```

[image]